# How to change state to unchecked/false when tapping on a checkbox in indeterminate state. React MUI Checkbox

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, material-ui

I have a header checkbox that should act as a select all or deselect all. I also have an indeterminate state for it when some records are selected but not all.

**The behavior I want is:**

When the user taps on the header checkbox while it is in the *indeterminate* state, it should deselect all the records. But instead, it is selecting all.

```
<Checkbox
    indeterminate={numSelected > 0 && numSelected < rowCount}
    checked={rowCount > 0 && numSelected === rowCount}
    onChange={onSelectAllClick}
/>
```

Below is the code for `onSelectAllClick`

```
const onSelectAllClick= (event) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
        const newSelectedRecords= records.map((r) => n.serialNumber);
        setSelected(newSelectedRecords);
    } else {
        setSelected([]);
    }
};
```

*numSelected* is the number of rows selected.

[Description Image of Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBL41.png)

Comment: try this `indeterminate={!(numSelected > 0 && numSelected < rowCount)}`

Comment: Wouldn't that just trigger indeterminate when nothing has been selected

Comment: What does the `onSelectAllClick` implementation look like?

Comment: you can make it in onSelectAllClick, when the checkbox is indeterminate, just send the checked value = false.
You need to post your current onSelectAllClick first

Comment: @gerrod I have added the code for onSelectAllClick in the question

Comment: @ĐỗNhậtQuang I am using that `onSelectAllClick` to select all or deselect all the checkboxes in the body. I have added the code for that in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// can useMemo
const indeterminate = numSelected > 0 && numSelected < rowCount
const onSelectAllClick= (event) => {
 if (event.target.checked && !indeterminate ) {
    const newSelectedRecords= records.map((r) => n.serialNumber);
    setSelected(newSelectedRecords);
 } else {
    setSelected([]);
 }
};

<Checkbox
    indeterminate={indeterminate}
    checked={rowCount > 0 && numSelected === rowCount}
    onChange={onSelectAllClick}/>
```

then you can add conditions on onChange like this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am too late but you can use `toggleAllPageRowsSelected()` or `togglePageRowsSelected()` from `useRowSelect` (https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useRowSelect)

```
const checked = nbSelectedRows === page.length;

const onChange = (event) => {
    if (indeterminate && event.target.checked === true) toggleAllPageRowsSelected(false);
    if (checked === true) toggleAllPageRowsSelected(false);
    if (checked === false && !indeterminate) toggleAllPageRowsSelected(true);
    };

<Checkbox            .
   checked={checked}
   indeterminate={indeterminate}
   onChange={(e) => { onChange(e, checked); }}
/>
```

Something like this